# Installing Poco on Mac

Tags: c++, makefile, osx-yosemite, poco-libraries, make-install

I am trying to install Poco on Mac. I downloaded the basic edition from [here](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html). As per the instructions, I did `configure`, then did `make`. It took a long time, but it succeeded (my `make` version is 3.81).

After this, when I did `sudo make install`, it finished pretty quickly. But as per the documentation, which states that I should have the libraries installed in `/usr/local`, I don't see them. The `/user/local/include/Poco` has all necessary header files, and `/user/local/lib` has lot of dynamic libraries like `libPocoFoundationd.30.dylib`, etc, but I don't see the libraries which I need to use.

How do I get them? My system is OS X 10.10, Yosemite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the entries like libPoco*.30.dylib (dynamic library binary) and libPoco*.dylib (link to the library), that's it. If you are looking for the static libraries, they are not built by default. To build static libraries, do

```
configure --static
```

and, after make install, in /usr/local/lib you will find libPoco*.a etc.

Comment: Oh ok. Will both work in the same way as far as my code is concerned?

Comment: They will provide the same functionality, but they do not "work" the same way - static libraries are linked at build time, dynamic at runtime. See [Overview of Dynamic Libraries](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/OverviewOfDynamicLibraries.html) for details.

Comment: So it looks like given the option to use both, dynamic libraries are better to use.